# How to get cash summary report using Xero API

Tags: xero-api

I have noticed a general trend that most of the helpful information is not available to pull from the Xero API (eg cash summary or import bank statement lines).
What I don't understand is how is that g-accon (https://www.g-accon.com/) is able to provide these reports if it is not available through the API? what am I missing?

I have developed a google apps script to get the trial balance from Xero so that I can build the balance sheet and P&L. The next step was the cash summary report but given the limitations above it seems like it is not possible (at least for my level of knowledge)?

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have looked at the API documentation, API explorer and xero.uservoice.com all of which point to not be being able to use API to get cash summary report or bank statement lines...

Comment: would anyone be able to have a quick chat me?